# android fragments flapping during app startup

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

Why would my Fragment be flapping during app startup?!?

```
02-10 11:41:34.699: D/SessionDetailFragment(19272): onResume() 99
02-10 11:41:34.699: D/MPQAudioFragment(19272): onResume() 00
02-10 11:41:34.699: D/MPQAudioFragment(19272): onResume() 99
02-10 11:41:34.699: D/SessionDetailFragment(19272): onPause() 00
02-10 11:41:34.699: D/MPQAudioFragment(19272): onStop() 00 bound_flag: false
02-10 11:41:34.699: D/MPQAudioFragment(19272): onStop() 05 mAudioService: null
02-10 11:41:34.699: D/SessionDetailFragment(19272): onStop() 00 bound_flag: false
02-10 11:41:34.699: D/SessionDetailFragment(19272): onStop() 05 mAudioService: null
02-10 11:41:34.709: D/SessionDetailFragment(19272): onDetach() 00
02-10 11:41:34.709: D/SessionDetailFragment(19272): onAttach() 00
02-10 11:41:34.709: D/SessionDetailFragment(19272): onAttach() 10 activity:MPQMainTabActivity
```

Note that as soon as `SessionDetailFragment` completes `onResume()` (as does its sub-Fragment `MPQAudioFragment`), they immediately run `onPause()`?!?!  Then as soon as the fragment is torn down, it again begins the `onAttach()` routine?

Fortunately this flapping only seems to occur once, but it makes maintaining state a bit more challenging (and I would like to understand what is happening and why).

---

#### UPDATE:

For now, I'm working around the flapping problem by using `static` member attributes for key data.

This SO post points to cases where `onSaveInstanceState()` does not get called, and potential workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909211/1742657

Comment: even worse - `onSaveInstanceState()` does not appear to get called during this flap :( .  The only 'hack'/workaround I can see is using static member variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE/CLOSURE 2013-03-24:

The duplicate Fragments appear to be caused by a parent/wrapper `TabHost`, and multiple calls to `updateTab` methods.  The first call would be from user presses of buttons and menus, and the second call would come from `onTabChanged()` triggered by the Listener.

Both calls would check for an existing fragment, but since instantiation had not been completed, both ended up creating a new fragment.